# Android calculate download speed test

Tags: android, performance, testing, download

I am trying to calculate a download speed test calculate.
Found a lot info in Stackoverflow but nothing help me.
The final calculation is not logic.
Trying to know the download speed in the while thread.
Attached my code that I found.

```
 public void run() {
            OutputStream out = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            try
            {
                URL url1 = new URL("test");
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getVideoFile().getPath()));
                conn = url1.openConnection();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int numRead;
                long numWritten = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    numWritten += numRead;

                    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if ((end - start)>0) {
                        double rate = 1000f *  numWritten / (end - start) ;
                        Log.d("downloadmanager","speed "+rate);
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("downloadmanager","Unknown Error: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if (in != null)
                    {
                        in.close();
                    }
                    if (out != null)
                    {
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.d("downloadmanager", "Unknown Error: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Thanks for helping figure this up.

Comment: what do you mean by *is not logic.* ?

Comment: The numbers are very high and I am not sure the calculate is right.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this way, hope it will help!
The change is , I have used set of url's.

```
    public class TestSpeed extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


    String TAG = "TestSpeed";
    long startTime,endTime,contentLength;
    String vURL[] = {
            "http://test/url/file1",
            "http://test/url/file2",
            "http://test/url/file3",
            "http://test/url/file4",
            "http://test/url/file5",
            "http://test/url/file6",
            "http://test/url/file7"
            "http://test/url/file8"
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        setCall(vURL[GlobalData.URLIndex]);
        GlobalData.URLIndex += 1;
        if(GlobalData.URLIndex >= vURL.length){
            GlobalData.URLIndex = 0;
        }
        return null;
    }

    void setCall(String URL){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Start " + URL);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Hold StartTime
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(URL).toURI());
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  //Hold EndTime

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity;
            bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

            //You can check the size of your file
            contentLength = bufHttpEntity.getContentLength();

            // Log
            Log.d("TAG", "Dowload time :" + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
            // Speed : size(KB)/time(s)
            Long mSpeed = contentLength / ((endTime - startTime) * 1000);
            Log.d(TAG, "mSpeed :" + mSpeed);

            Double duration = Double.valueOf((endTime - startTime));
            Double speedKbps = Double.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(Double.valueOf(contentLength / 1024)));
            Double speedMbps = roundTwoDecimals(speedKbps / 1024);
            Log.d(TAG,"" + speedKbps);
            Log.d(TAG,"" + speedMbps);

            //confirm units for display
            String mTheSpeed = "" + speedMbps;
            String speed;
            if(mTheSpeed.charAt(0) == '0'){
                speed = roundTwoDecimals(speedKbps) + " kb/s";
            }else{
                speed = roundTwoDecimals(speedMbps) + " mb/s";
            }

            Log.d("Speed Result: ","" + speed);

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Double roundTwoDecimals(Double vLongValue)
    {
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(vLongValue));
    }
}
```

For an alternative you can go with the [WifiInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed()), the code looks like this.

```
private static Integer wifiSpeed(Context mContext){
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager);
      mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
      Integer wifiSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
      return wifiSpeed;
}
```

Comment: WifiInfo will give you estimated LinkSpeed of the wifi connection. This is not the download speed you would get if you were to download a file from the internet.  More comprehensive answer can be found in this thread> 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193518/how-to-measure-upload-download-speed-and-latency-in-android-wifi-connection/64821598#64821598